# Scroll to top of page after delay (just once) or after an iFrame on page has loaded the first time

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have a parent page containing an iFrame midway down the page (same domain, have access to both). My iFrame tag looks like this:

```
<iframe name="Survey" onload="parent.location='https://www.example.com/ParentPage#SurveyTop';" scrolling="no" src="https://www.example.com/ChildPage" width="100%" id="iFrameResizer0">
```

The iFrame can get quite tall, so I have that onload command in the iFrame tag which makes the page automatically back to the top of the iFrame every time the iFrame is refreshed/loaded.

The problem is that it also immediately scrolls down to the top of the iFrame the first time the parent page is loaded, since the contents of the iFrame loads a second or two after the parent page. So the visitor never sees all the important page name/intro/hero image stuff above the iFrame.

Is there some javascript where I can initially have the parent page displayed at the top of the page, but any time the content in the iFrame is refreshed it scrolls to the top of the iFrame like it does now?

I tried putting various methods javascript after the iFrame thinking it would load and scroll to the iFrame, but then scroll back up to the top if the page, but it never worked. For example:

```
document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
```

or

```
window.scrollTo(x-coord, y-coord);
```

I also tried putting a three second delay on it but it still didn't scroll to the top. (My scripting is terrible). It's not ideal to have the page jump down to the iFrame then back to the top, but it would only happen the first time and it's a compromise I'm willing to have! Thanks!

Comment: Actually, if I do 
`document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;`
in the Chrome console, it does go back to the top. But I think I need to just add a two or three second delay. Can someone let me know how to run that script after a delay? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say you "tried putting a three second delay on it", what code did you use? Then in your comment you ask how to create a delay... It isn't clear what method you tried that failed to work. Anyhow, to add a 3 sec delay in Javascript execution, the standard method to use is `window.setTimeout(function(){YOURCODE;}, 3000);`. As you noted, this would be a compromise, not really the solution you want.

A better approach would be to set an onload handler on the parent window, which would set the onload handler of the iFrame: `window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {YOURCODE;}, false);`. In your code in the handler you'd reference the iFrame with `window.frames["iFrameResizer0"]`.

Because the iFrame onload handler would be set after the parent page and the iFrame have loaded, the iFrame onload code would only run when the iFrame is reloaded, not on the first load of the parent, solving your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was able to ask a buddy about this and he suggested the exact same thing you did (your "better approach" answer). Works like a charm now. Thanks again for your input!